# Don't understand why this float issue is occurring

Tags: python, numpy

I keep getting the same error message and I don't know why.

```
def function_to_fit(x, a, b):
    return (a*x) + b

fit_guess = np.array([ 2., 0.])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(function_to_fit, x, y, sigma=y_err, p0=fit_guess)
print("Fit Parameters:", popt)
print("Fit Parameter Uncertainties:", np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))

# calculate chi^2 and reduced chi^2
chi2 = np.sum(((y-function_to_fit(x, *popt))/y_err)**2)
print("chi^2:", chi2)
print("Reduced chi^2:", chi2/(len(x) - len(fit_guess)))
```

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? Also, what are the values for the variables you are using (`x`,`y`, etc.)?

Comment: This is a common error message when you think you're multiplying two floats, or a numpy array by a float -- but you're accidentally actually multiplying a string, list, or tuple ("sequences") by a float, which obviously isn't possible. A more detailed error message and more information could help clarify this.

Comment: Give as a little more information on your data. Did you pass your ``x` and `y` to arrays? If they are stored in a `list` or `tuple`, using `x = np.array(x)` and `y=np.array(y)` before calling `curve_fit`, will likely solve the problem

Comment: @JoePatten the error is on the chi2 line, and x and y are                  x = (-2.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0)
y = (17.3,18.9,10.3,11.4,2.7,3.7,-3.5, -4.0, -7.9,-12.1, -17.3, -15.9)
y_err = (2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0)